# How to measure the force by which Two rigid Bodies collide?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

How to measure the force by which Two rigid Bodies collide and in the reaction add force to other object in opposite direction. For example in the cricket game how the force is measured b/w bat and ball . If player blocks it add a min force to the ball and if he plays the shot he ball goes too far for a four or a six. I will say that just simple addforce() component will not work. It will just apply the force every time when it hits the bat doesn't matter it is blocked or a shot played.

Comment: Please clarify your question and post some code indicating your problem. SO is not the proper place for answering physics questions!

Comment: I have given the unity tag and i am working on he cricket game in unity and having the problem to measure the force by which ball is hit with the bat, Clear?

Comment: Well that last sentence was just sarcasm.. sorry if it annoyed you. If your question does not meet SO guidelines, it will be flagged and closed by the moderators. I'm trying to help you prevent this and get a good answer to your question. You need to post what code you have tried and ask about a specific issue/bug.